# My links shift to the left when clicked

Tags: css

I'm designing a website and having a problem with my links. When I click on them they shift to the left. Sometimes this prevents them from actually being clickable. I have not been able to find a single solution through googling and have no idea what part of my code is causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

[Website](http://www.thefilterconnection.com/shopsite_sc/store/html/LEE_Seven5_Holders_Adapter_Rings.html)

```css
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 color: #151515;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: small;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}
 #header {
 background-color: #171717;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 height: 75px;
 width: 100%;
}
 #header1 {
 padding-top: 21px;
 background-color: #171717;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

 #header2   {
 background-color: #171717;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 width: 20%;
 padding-top: 33px;
 font-size: 11px;
}
 #header2 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 background-color: undefined;
 font-size: small;
}
 #header2 a {
 width: 20%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #CCCCCC;
}
 #header2 a:hover , a:active, a:focus{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 float: left;
}

 #header3 {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 11px;
 padding-top: 23px;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px;
 }
 #search {
 width: 15%;
}
 #search input[type="text"] {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 10px 6px;
 background-image: url(https://gray.secure-host.com/thefilterconnection/shopsite_sc/store/html/media/search-dark.png);
 background-color: #909090;
 border: 0 none;
 font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
 color: #CCCCCC;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-bottom: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
 transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
 padding-left: 35px;
    }
 #header4 {
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 16px;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #CCCCCC;
}
 #header5 {
 width: 20%;
 background-color: #171717;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 13px;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
 color: #CCCCCC;
}

 #productmenucontainer {
 background-color: #171717;
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
 float: center;
 height: 30px;
}
 #productmenu {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #171717;
 padding-top: 3px;
 text-align: center;
 right: auto;
 left: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
 #container1 {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #EBEBEB;
 position: relative;
 right: 75%;
}
 #container2 {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
 #container3 {
 min-width: 740px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 clear: left;
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #DBDBDB;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px #DBDBDB;
 width: 100%;
}
 #sidebar1 {
 float: left;
 width: 17%;
 position: relative;
 left: 75%;
 padding-left: 4%;
 padding-top: 2%;
 text-align: left;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-right: 4%;
}
 #sidebar1 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: -25px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}
 #main {
 float: left;
 width: 64%;
 position: relative;
 left: 75%;
 padding-left: 4%;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-right: 4%;
}
 #footer {
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 font-weight: lighter;
 padding-top: 4px;
 font-size: 11px;
 text-align: center;
 clear: left;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 color: #6C6C6C;
 min-width: 740px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
 #disclaimer   {
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 width: 23%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
}
 #creditcards {
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
 #share {
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
}



 #follow {
 float: left;
 padding-top: 5px;
 width: 20%;
}
 #copyright {
 clear: left;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #626262;
 color: #F3F3F3;
 font-size: x-small;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
}
a:link {
 color: #575757;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: small;
}
a:visited {
 color: #6C6C6C;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #7F7F7F;
}
.menu {
 background-color: #B1CCE0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 740px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 left: auto;
 right: auto;
 float: left;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.menu > span {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 #nav {
 display: inline;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
 z-index: 1000;
}
 #nav > li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 color: #6C6C6C;
}
 #nav > li > a {
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 color: #CCCCCC;
 display: block;
 font-size: small;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bolder;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0;
 box-shadow: 0px 0;
 text-shadow: 0px 0;
}
 #nav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #e4ecf4;
 border-color: #999;
}
 #nav > li.selected  > a {
 background-color: #171717;
 border-color: #999999 #999999 #FFFFFF;
 z-index: 2;
}
 #nav li div {
    position:relative;
}
 #nav li div div {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 padding: 12px 0;
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: -1px;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 190px;
}
 #nav li div div.wrp2 {
 width: 380px;
 background-color: #171717;
}
 #nav .sep {
    left:190px;
    border-left:1px solid #E3E3E3;
    bottom:0;
    height:auto;
    margin:15px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:1px;
}
 #nav li div ul {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
 width: 170px;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: #171717;
}
 #nav li div ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
 #nav li div ul li h3 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
 color: #4F87C5;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0 5px 4px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 font-size: small;
}
 #nav li div ul li h3 a {
 color: #4F87C5;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: small;
}
 #nav li div ul li h3 a:hover {
 color: #89B3E1;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: small;
}


 #nav li ul ul {
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 bottom: 8px;
}
 #nav li ul ul li {
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
 #nav li ul ul li a {
 color: #CCCCCC;
 display: block;

 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
 #nav li ul ul li a:hover{
 background-color: #171717;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: float:left on active??

Answer (score 0):

```
#header2 a:hover , a:active, a:focus{
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
**float: left;**
}
```

This is the part I'm most suspicious of. What happens without the float: left - or, if you apply it to those links in their original CSS rule, not the :active one?

Comment: that's not exactly an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your css file demopage.css on line 61, you need to remove a:active and a:focus from that declaration. Basically on every click on all a tags on your page they get a float: left value. So if you remove them from it everything will work perfectly :)

I have tested it on your site and it works :)

So from this

```
#header2 a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
}
```

to this

```
#header2 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
}
```